# Retrieve Case Action - Send Email Metadata in VsCode

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, vs-code

I have made changes to the pre-defined field values section of Case Action:Email in my scratch org. Upon pulling, VsCode retrieves nothing. Can someone help? 
How should I commit this change and under what metadata component.

Comment: What have you tried pulling exactly? Case object, quick action, etc?

Comment: Trying to pull The email standard quick action within Case object

Comment: Weird enough, I just changed the description of the Send Email quick action and did a source:pull, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package.xml to retrieve the quickaction. Right click on it in folder structure and choose **retieve source in Manifest from org**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

the above package will retrieve all the quickaction you have in authorised org.

[image]

The retrieved metadata of Email quickaction will look like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>true</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <quickActionLayout>
        <layoutSectionStyle>TwoColumnsLeftToRight</layoutSectionStyle>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>ValidatedFromAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Required</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>ToAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>CcAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>BccAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Subject</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>HtmlBody</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>RelatedToId</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>EmailTemplateId</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
        </quickActionLayoutColumns>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns/>
    </quickActionLayout>
    <standardLabel>SendEmail</standardLabel>
    <targetObject>OutgoingEmail</targetObject>
    <type>SendEmail</type>
</QuickAction>
```